# Transfer files between two computers connected by KVM

Tags: windows, linux, ubuntu, file-transfer, kvm-switch

I have a Windows 7 Desktop and an Ubuntu Laptop connected with a KVM switch. I use the setup for software development, so I am constantly switching between the two, so I need a way to quickly transfer files between the two. I'm not sure if this is possible, but if I could connect them in a way where the OS of each mounts the hard drive of the other. Is there a way I could do this? Thanks!

Comment: btw, linux is a pretty broad tag. You might want to try tagging as Ubuntu for some more friendly distribution tools.

Comment: or use a sneaker-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could setup [Samba](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/install-samba-server-on-ubuntu/) on the Linux machine, and share a folder out to windows machines.  Then map that as a network drive on windows.

From Linux, you can connect to smb shares.  So setup a folder on your windows machine, and [mount it](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=284436) in Ubuntu.

Although, it might be fastest/best to pick one machine (Probably not the laptop because of speed) and put all your files there.  Then, just mount the share from Ubuntu (linked to above), and save all changes from both windows and Ubuntu to there.  That way, there is no more copying, and just one spot for all your code.  (and just one spot to back up!)

Comment: I like the last idea, I'll give it a try. Never really thought about that, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

There's always [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/).

Answer (score 0):

if you have python installed:

change to the directory you want to export

```
python -c ”import SimpleHTTPServer;SimpleHTTPServer.test()”
```

open browser on the client"

http://your_ip:8000/

this is readonly sharing (not to spread viruses)